# Nature of cryptic prophecies

Tags: tanach, nevua-prophecy, prophecies

I understand that prophecies in the Tanach seem to be very cryptic until the prophecy actually happens: then do the verses become clear and be correlated to the happened events. What are good examples of such a cryptic prophecy in Tanach?

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15215.

Comment: I don't think I would say that it is always the case that the prophecies are cryptic. Although they certainly are sometimes.

Comment: I think that this misses an important point -- nevu'ah isn't always a predictive prophecy which has to be confirmed. It could be a warning of a consequence which can be averted, or a scolding over behavior already past.