# Is any of Tehillim considered prophecy?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, nevua-prophecy, king-david, ymoth-hamoshiach

Most of Tehillim was written by David about himself. Are there any psalms that are considered prophecy or even messianic prophecy?

Comment: Rosh hashana 4a

Comment: and: https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.57b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Wouldn't *Al Naharot Bavel* be one example? How could David write about the destruction of the *Bet Hamikdash* unless he was prophetic?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26949

Comment: Wait, doesn't the Gemmorah say that others actually wrote it centuries after?

Comment: Bava Batra 14b-15a, Rashi to Megillah 3a, 14a 9https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_Bible#Development_and_codification(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mahartaz Chayus says (Rosh Hashana 4a) that it is perplexing why the Talmud (ibid.) refers to one of the psalm’s authors as prophet. He goes on to say that Tehilim is not said with *nevuah* only with *ruach hakodesh*.

Comment: very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ibn Ezra says that the doxology that closes [*T'hilim* 89](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Tehillim/89.53#e0n6) is David Hamelech's reaction to a messianic prophecy:

> בָּר֖וּךְ ה' לְ֝עוֹלָ֗ם אָ֘מֵ֥ן וְאָמֵֽן׃

. . . about which he comments

> הטעם שראה המשורר ברוח הקודש ביאת המשיח, על כן נתן הודות לשם.

This explanation may arise from a need to identify the motivation for this otherwise incongruously exultive line following a section of scathing despair over adversarial strife.

Comment: Beautiful final sentence. +1

Comment: ...how ever he says ruach hakodesh, which is not nevuah.