# In Judaism, what prophetic event or promise to Israel took the longest time to fulfill?

Tags: time, nevua-prophecy

In scriptures it appears that the longest time it took several prophecies to happen to Israel as a people is between 70-430 years, 430 years having been the longest recorded for fulfilment of a prophecy concerning Israel as a people.

Is there another longer prophecy to fulfill?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77333

Comment: "In scriptures it appears": can you [edit] to clarify how that appears? Especially the 450-year one, since more info on that one may help someone answer your question.

Comment: Also note that some prophecies are believed not to have been fulfilled yet. Can you [edit] to clarify how you would count these? For example, is the earliest-made as-yet-unfulfilled prophecy considered the one that took longest to fulfill and thus the answer to your question?

Comment: What about the coming of the mashiach and the rebuilding of the Temple, which has not happened yet.

Comment: How about when Jacob is about to tell his sons what happens at the end of days? Midrash says he was made to forget, but he obviously prophesied it so he could mention it.

Comment: @sabbahillel as to the coming of mashiach, I  acquiesce. However as to the building of the temple, do you mean that 'seen' by Ezekiel 'on the mount'?

Comment: @ Clint Eastwood how should we understand the meaning of 'end of days'? To what does it refer?

Comment: @ClintEastwood IIRC this was about Yetzias Mitzraim which occured 120 years after Yaakov and the family came down. He was unable to tell them the precise time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we wait for all the prophecies about the end of this last Exile.

But meanwhile, we already saw a lot of another.
A few examples:

- In parashas ניצבים , the Tora says that "stranger that would come from a far country would see the Land and its plagues ... and say 'why did G-d that to this land ... And He threw them from their country ...to another land like today' "...

> והנכרי אשר יבא מארץ רחוקה ... ואמרו על מה עשה ד' ככה לארץ הזאת ... וישליכם אל ארץ אחרת כיום הזה

...**3200 years after**, Mark Twain told these questions and answer about Eretz Israel.

- In the curses of כי תבא , the Tora predicts about an enemy that would come "like the fly of the eagle" and that would not have mercy for the elder or on the young

> גוי ... כאשר ידאה הנשר ... אשר לא ישא פנים לזקן ונער לא יחון

Some say that could be about the **Nazis**, whom they symbol was an eagle (and obviously, were very cruel)
Nachmanides (in נצבים IIRC) already said that we have seen almost all the curses accomplished in the Exile...

- See the documentary ['Germamia'](https://youtu.be/L6Mq-9yZvFY) where the Rav Ron Shaya details the prophecies about Edom countries and **WWII**, that were told at least 2000 years before... [And even how the Megilas Esther *alludes* on the 11 Nuremberg accused in the year 5706...]
- And a lot more...

I presently not remember exactly all the sources, but I think R Ezriel Tauber brings the first example above.

Comment: How do you know that no one before Mark Twain expressed his sentiment (albeit privately, or to a small crowd lost to history)?

Comment: The Eagle could have been the Roman empire

Comment: @ShmuelBrin כאשר ידאה means quickly, and the German Army used the Blitzkrieg. But I agree, it is not sure.