# Catholic interested in learning about Judaism ✡️ & learning Hebrew to better understand the difference between the Bible & the Torah 

Tags: torah-study, hebrew, tanach, translation

I don’t know much about the Jewish Faith. During my younger years I attended Catholic School until 10th grade. Recently I have become stronger Spiritually, I’ve always had a strong curiousity about your Faith. What I’m most curious about are the differences between Catholicism & Judaism, I guess mostly in the translation from the Torah to the Bible.

At this time I’m looking for ideas re: where to start with my Hebrew studies, perhaps Duolingo with another app & an extremely patient Rabbi  I gotta give it up to you guys bc I looked at a lesson on Duolingo, probably should’ve taken a pic to make u all smile  I was a wreck, the lesson was supposed to be 5 min, it was 20  I’m determined though

Any app recommendations or literally anything u think a Non-Jewish person should try to gain knowledge, send them my way please ❤️

Comment: First of all, considering you posted this I guess you found this site while searching online, so I’m sure you can find plenty of people here (including me) who are willing to help you or answer any questions you have. Secondly, yes you should definitely find a rabbi irl that you can form a relationship with because everyone needs a rabbi to help them learn and guide them

Comment: Continuing from above, what exactly is your purpose in learning Hebrew? Like it’s good and all to know but it’ll take a long time and the Torah or Gemara or whatever commentaries you want to learn are all in weird and hard to understand Hebrew so even if you learn Hebrew you might have trouble deciphering them. So I would simply recommend using the English translation of whatever it is you want to learn because let’s face it, everything is translated into English and yeah that’s about all I can say as of now lol

Comment: I wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95567/11501) on this site about book recommendations to learn about Judaism. Learning Hebrew is a very significant effort which will prove useful if you are serious about Judaism, but can likely wait since so much material exists in English

Comment: Check out Rabbi Tovia Singer to find out about differences between Jewish Bible and Christian version.

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84689/15256

Comment: https://www.jewfaq.org/

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice 

Comment: Curious Yid-I think learning Hebrew is more about my curiousity about your Faith, like will it make it easier learning some Hebrew. Lots of factors n curiousity going on over here ☺️

Comment: Subscribe to Tovia Singer, Jews for Judaism (Rabbi Skobac) and Rabbi Manis Friedman on youtube. The former two specialise in teaching Torah to gentiles and giving them access to the language. The latter has had many Christian groups and classes come to him in the past and has a few videos that are Christian friendly.

Answer (score 4):

1. **If your goal is specifically studying Torah to examine accurate English Translations printed below the Hebrew Text**, you could research Schottenstein's Interlinear Pentateuch by Artscroll.
2. **If your goal is to distinguish English errors in the KJV translations of Tanakh**, you could research Volume 1 of "Let's Get Biblical" by Rabbi Tovia Singer.

- Note : English KJV Translation of Tanakh was based on an alternative Greek manuscript called 'Codex Receptus' by Erasmus which shows textual differences compared to older Greek Septuagint manuscripts like Codex Sinaiticus.

May your Hebrew studies bring you joy, and help your ability to share Torah with others.